# Nervgh Angular FileUpload ng-repeat unique instances of uploader

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload

I need a number of Nervgh-uploader.

I have an array "variations" and I add an uploader-instance to each variation object.

```
// Configure uploader
var uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: 'http://....php'
});

$scope.variations[i].uploader = uploader;
```

In HTML I do ng-repeat on variations

```
<div ng-repeat="variation in variations">...</div>
```

I want those divs to be dropzones for particular uploader

```
<div ng-repeat="variation in variations" nv-file-drop="" uploader="variation.uploader">...</div>
```

Probably variation in the attribute is not "logically linked" to variation in the loop. I guess Nervgh looks it up in $scope.variation.uploader, if any it can handle childs.

But how to deal with it?

Chris